# Is there a way to convert function type in haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I am fairly new to haskell and I run into this problem with type converting a function. Let's say I don't know anything about a function other than its function type. Is it possible to convert its function type and put it as a new function.
For example

```
myfunc:: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
myfunc inputfunc = (function with type (Integer -> Integer -> Integer))
```

Are there ways to do such a thing?

Comment: Converting from `Int -> Int -> Int` to `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` isn’t safe in general because it means someone can pass an argument to the new function that’s out of the range of `Int`.

Comment: But lets say if I only want to convert and do not care about being "safe". Is there a method for such conversion

Comment: `\f x y -> fromIntegral (fromIntegral x \`f\` fromIntegral y)`

Comment: No, there isn’t. (Unless you’re okay with defining what all the “correct” conversions are and enabling a bunch of extensions. Then there might be a way. [And there *is* something straightforward and still unpleasant in that vein with Template Haskell.] But seriously, just write it out instead.)

Comment: @RyanO'Hara I think you have that backwards. `Int` is fixed (machine word size) precision and `Integer` is arbitrary precision. Also, even converting the other direction, you don't need to do anything fancy like that. You just need to use `fromIntegral`, which is a part of the standard Prelude (nothing needs to be imported for that, let alone needing extensions and definitely not Template Haskell).

Comment: Additionally, if you want more safety, you could just use write a small wrapper around `fromIntegral` using `Maybe` or `Either`, which is a pretty standard Haskell technique for dealing with that sort of situation (when you do need that extra bit of added safety).

Comment: @DavidYoung: Original function accepts `Int`. Converted function accepts `Integer`. Pass `1000000000000000000000` and…? You can safely use `fromIntegral` on the result, but I wrote “pass an argument”.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Ahh, that's a good point. However, there is nothing tricky about implementing the unsafe version of this conversion. Unless I misunderstood, it sounds like you were saying that you needed to do some advanced things on the level of Template Haskell in order to perform the conversion.

Comment: @DavidYoung: If I had to make a generic way to take functions `a -> b -> c -> … -> x` and turn them into `a' -> b' -> c' -> … -> x'` based on predefined `a -> a', …, x -> x'` conversion functions, I would probably start by trying Template Haskell. There might be other extensions that would work too. For a specific case, of course you can just convert everything individually, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained by others, what you want is basically this:

```
convert f x y = fromIntegral (f (fromIntegral x) (fromIntegral y))
```

This is pretty straightforward. However, if I were to do it, I'd take advantage of the `on` function from `Data.Function`, which converts the inputs of functions that take two arguments before applying it. So, in your example, it would look like this:

```
convert f x y = fromIntegral ((f `on` fromIntegral) x y)
```

I, personally, would go one step further and make this function point-free, but because `on f fromIntegral` expects two arguments, you can't just use `(.)`, so I usually define an operator for this:

```
(.:) = (.) . (.)
```

You can figure out why this works on your own if you'd like, but now I can define convert as this:

```
convert f = fromIntegral .: (f `on` fromIntegral)
```

I feel that this is a lot more readable, but I am biased because I have been coding Haskell like this for a while now.

Also, if you look at the inferred type of this variable, you'd see that it's much more general than what you wanted:

```
 convert :: (Integral a, Integral a1, Num b, Num b1) = (b1 -> b1 -> a) -> a1 -> a1 -> b
```

Anyway, I hope this is somewhat useful.

I really don't mean for this post to intimidate you as a newcomer, so if any of it confuses you, please ask me questions and I'd happily answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- `(Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)` can also be written `(Int -> Int -> Int) -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer`. It is a function of three arguments.
- [Converting Numbers](https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers#Converting_from_and_between_integral_types_.28integer-like_types.29)

Comment: I look at the link, and the conversion basically require us to know the functions before hand. What if the inputfunc is a blackbox function we don't know, can we still convert such a function?

Comment: @user3595342 rewrite `myfunc` as a function of three arguments. Create arguments to supply the inputfunc, and then process it's output.